# VB6 app crashes when key is held down

Tags: vb6, crash, keypress, crash-dumps

I have a VB6 application with a form that processes input via its KeyPress event. In that method, it checks to see what ASCII code has been passed in via a series of if statements, and runs the necessary code to respond to the input. So, the basic format is:

```
Private Sub Form_Keypress (KeyAscii As Integer)

If KeyAscii = 97
' Do some stuff

If KeyAscii = 98
' Do some different stuff

End Sub
```

There are 24 keys connected to a keyboard encoder that provide input from buttons on the front of the kiosk. The OS is Windows 7. The problem that I have is if I hold one of these keys down for about ten seconds, the app simply crashes -- no exception, just stops executing. I did collect a few mini-dumps, and I don't see anything that gives me any usable information, but I am not experienced in reading them.

I need to know why the app can't seem to handle a stream of key presses and how to get around it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd re-code it to look more like this:

```
Private Sub Form_Keypress (KeyAscii As Integer)
    Static bInKeyPress As Boolean
    If bInKeyPress = True Then Exit Sub

    On Error GoTo Handler

    bInKeyPress = True

    If KeyAscii = 97
        ' Do some stuff

    ElseIf KeyAscii = 98
        ' Do some different stuff

' Everything goes through here, after execution is complete.
' Handler also calls through to this, to make sure we clean up things
ExitPoint:
    bInKeyPress = False
    Exit Sub

'Do any error handling / logging you want, here, then clean things up.
Handler:
    GoTo ExitPoint
End Sub
```

Use a Static variable inside the Sub itself if you don't want anything else to be able to reset the variable, and it'll only toggle back to False when your processing finishes.  Use a Private variable at the module level if you think something else should be able to control whether the Keypress function needs to be enabled or not.

Basically, you're wanting to stop listening to key presses whilst processing anything.

---

**EDIT**: *Cleaned this up to align with some of the suggestions in the comments, and to clarify the program flow.*

Comment: +1 though I use this method frequently, but always put `If bInKeyPress = True Then Exit Sub` at the first line of the Sub, before the error handler, and put `Static bInKeyPress as Boolean` outside the Sub. This cuts down on the instructions needed before exiting, importantly cutting down call stack size, which was likely the original problem.

Comment: @DanVerdolino Agreed, that putting it before the `On Error` statement makes good sense.  Putting it outside the procedure itself, though, will make it accessible to methods outside the procedure, which may or may not be desirable.

Comment: Maybe I'm just missing it, but where is bInKeyPress getting set back to false aside from the error handler? Should I set it back after I perform the processing in each key press check?

Comment: In VB6, execution will continue through the handler after you `' Do some different stuff`

Comment: Let me rephrase: `Handler:` is just a label for a location in code. It is only called an "error handler" because we point to it with `On Error GoTo Handler`. It is very different from a `Try...Catch` block.

Comment: @DanVerdolino I've tweaked the answer a bit, to move the `If bInKeyPress` statement before the `On Error Goto` Statement, and also to separate the `Handler` section from `ExitPoint` (for cleanup).  This way it serves as a better example, I think.

Comment: @DavidTMacknet very nice, that's how I would do it.